# Rmarkdown runs much more slowly than R script after update

Tags: r, performance, r-markdown

I recently updated to the latest versions of R and R Studio on my new M1 Max machine. After update, however, Rmarkdown runs very slow compared to a regular R script. For example, I ran a code on R script which took this long:

| user | system | Elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.437 | 0.037 | 0.490 |

When I ran the same script on Rmarkdown it took:

| user | system | Elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21.820 | 0.431 | 25.243 |

I have tried unistalling and reinstalling Rmarkdown package, and even R, Rstudio, and Anaconda but nothing is working.

Edit: This is with any code I run. For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
```

the following code:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()

mpg %>% 
  mutate(age = if_else(year > 2000, "New", "Old")) %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  summarize(cyl = mean(cyl, na.rm = TRUE))

Sys.time() - start_time
```

takes 0.02736592 secs on Rscript and 2.401871 secs on Rmarkdown.

Note: This happens when I have lots of data loaded in R. For this example, I had ~3GB of data loaded in R. When there is no data loaded to memory, performance is similar.

Comment: What's in the script?

Comment: @r2evans I just edited the question to include the script.

Comment: I don't see the full rmarkdown document, but if all you have is the code above, consider changing from `library(tidyverse)` to `library(dplyr)` since that's all you're using.

Comment: @r2evans tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I think it would be useful to have a more reproducible question.

Comment: @r2evans I, unfortunately, don't know how to make this a reproducible question because this happened after I updated my Rstudio and R.

Comment: We don't know the version of R or the libraries you're using, nor what they were before you migrated to a new system. We don't have a markdown document, just a simple dplyr pipe off of `mpg`. I understand your frustration, and if I knew of any changes to R that would recently cause a slowdown I would mention it, but ... there's very little to go on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the previous version of RStudio I was using (2022.07.2) and it seems to have solved the issue. It must be an issue with the recent release of Rstudio.